# FileMaker Relationship Using Embedded SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, filemaker

In table “Processor” I have a GTIN value. (see attached pict/link)

In “PROMPT” and “TEST” I have a return delimited value list of that GTIN just in different formats, removing some values from front and back of GTIN.

When I make a relationship from Processor’s GTIN to TEST’s GTINList, the ProductID value returns no problem.

When I make a relationship from Processor’s GTIN to PROMPT’s GTINList, the ProductID value does not return.

Here’s the difference.

TEST is a FileMaker Database

PROMPT is a SQL Table embedded in the FileMaker database.

The column type of GTINList is nchar(250) to allow Unicode data, I have tried varchar(250) as well.

Q:

Why does the SQL table not pull in the Product ID if values are identical in the TEST GTINList?

If I remove the paragraph returns and only put value 0007800001180 in GTINList, it does relate properly and ProductID is returned, so I know my relationship is accurate.

I create the GTINList with the following calcs.

--CARRIAGE RETURN
GTIN & Char(13) &
Middle ( GTIN ; 3 ; Length ( GTIN ) ) & Char(13) &
Middle ( GTIN ; 1 ; Length ( GTIN ) -1 )

--CARRIAGE RETURN & LINE FEED
GTIN & Char(13) & Char(10) &
Middle ( GTIN ; 3 ; Length ( GTIN ) ) & Char(13) & Char(10) &
Middle ( GTIN ; 1 ; Length ( GTIN ) -1 )

--LINE FEED
GTIN & Char(10) &
Middle ( GTIN ; 3 ; Length ( GTIN ) ) & Char(10) &
Middle ( GTIN ; 1 ; Length ( GTIN ) -1 )

--PARAGRAPH SYMBOL
GTIN & ¶ &
Middle ( GTIN ; 3 ; Length ( GTIN ) ) & ¶ &
Middle ( GTIN ; 1 ; Length ( GTIN ) -1 )
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8IBF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Multiline keys might not work in ESS. You can try ExecuteSQL function with like operator.